# Composer install times out with a bind-mounted volume running Composer through Docker

Tags: composer, 10

I've been working on trying to set up a Drupal 10 local development instance on my Windows machine and keep running into an issue of the Drupal installation failing when I have a volume mounted.

Following the instructions given on [Using Composer to Install Drupal and Manage Dependencies / Installing with Composer via Docker](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/using-composer/manage-dependencies#s-installing-with-composer-via-docker), I've run `docker run --rm -i --tty -v %cd%/drupal:/app/drupal composer create-project drupal/recommended-project drupal --ignore-platform-reqs`.

It shows the following output.

> Creating a "drupal/recommended-project" project at "./drupal"
> Installing drupal/recommended-project (10.0.9)
>
> - Downloading drupal/recommended-project (10.0.9)
> - Installing drupal/recommended-project (10.0.9): Extracting archive
>   Created project in /app/drupal
>
> Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
> Verifying lock file contents can be installed on current platform.
> Package operations: 54 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
>
> - Downloading composer/installers (v2.2.0)
> - Downloading drupal/core-composer-scaffold (10.0.9)
> - Downloading drupal/core-project-message (10.0.9)
> - Downloading symfony/polyfill-mbstring (v1.27.0)
> - Downloading symfony/polyfill-ctype (v1.27.0)
> - Downloading twig/twig (v3.5.1)
> - Downloading symfony/yaml (v6.2.10)
> - Downloading symfony/var-exporter (v6.2.10)
> - Downloading symfony/var-dumper (v6.2.10)
> - Downloading symfony/translation-contracts (v3.2.1)
> - Downloading symfony/deprecation-contracts (v3.2.1)
> - Downloading symfony/validator (v6.2.10)
> - Downloading symfony/polyfill-intl-normalizer (v1.27.0)
> - Downloading symfony/polyfill-intl-grapheme (v1.27.0)
> - Downloading symfony/string (v6.2.8)
> - Downloading psr/container (2.0.2)
> - Downloading symfony/service-contracts (v3.2.1)
> - Downloading symfony/serializer (v6.2.10)
> - Downloading symfony/routing (v6.2.8)
> - Downloading symfony/http-foundation (v6.2.10)
> - Downloading psr/http-message (1.0.1)
> - Downloading symfony/psr-http-message-bridge (v2.1.4)
> - Downloading symfony/process (v6.2.10)
> - Downloading symfony/polyfill-php72 (v1.27.0)
> - Downloading symfony/polyfill-intl-idn (v1.27.0)
> - Downloading symfony/polyfill-iconv (v1.27.0)
> - Downloading symfony/mime (v6.2.10)
> - Downloading psr/event-dispatcher (1.0.0)
> - Downloading symfony/event-dispatcher-contracts (v3.2.1)
> - Downloading symfony/event-dispatcher (v6.2.8)
> - Downloading psr/log (3.0.0)
> - Downloading symfony/error-handler (v6.2.10)
> - Downloading symfony/http-kernel (v6.2.10)
> - Downloading symfony/dependency-injection (v6.2.10)
> - Downloading symfony/console (v6.2.10)
> - Downloading ralouphie/getallheaders (3.0.3)
> - Downloading psr/http-factory (1.0.2)
> - Downloading psr/http-client (1.0.2)
> - Downloading psr/cache (3.0.0)
> - Downloading pear/pear_exception (v1.0.2)
> - Downloading pear/console_getopt (v1.4.3)
> - Downloading pear/pear-core-minimal (v1.10.13)
> - Downloading pear/archive_tar (1.4.14)
> - Downloading masterminds/html5 (2.7.6)
> - Downloading guzzlehttp/psr7 (2.4.5)
> - Downloading guzzlehttp/promises (1.5.2)
> - Downloading guzzlehttp/guzzle (7.5.1)
> - Downloading doctrine/lexer (1.2.3)
> - Downloading egulias/email-validator (3.2.5)
> - Downloading doctrine/annotations (1.13.3)
> - Downloading composer/semver (3.3.2)
> - Downloading asm89/stack-cors (v2.1.1)
> - Downloading drupal/core (10.0.9)
> - Installing composer/installers (v2.2.0): Extracting archive
> - Installing drupal/core-composer-scaffold (10.0.9): Extracting archive
> - Installing drupal/core-project-message (10.0.9): Extracting archive
> - Installing symfony/polyfill-mbstring (v1.27.0): Extracting archive
> - Installing symfony/polyfill-ctype (v1.27.0): Extracting archive
> - Installing twig/twig (v3.5.1): Extracting archive
> - Installing symfony/yaml (v6.2.10): Extracting archive
> - Installing symfony/var-exporter (v6.2.10): Extracting archive
> - Installing symfony/var-dumper (v6.2.10): Extracting archive
> - Installing symfony/translation-contracts (v3.2.1): Extracting archive
> - Installing symfony/deprecation-contracts (v3.2.1): Extracting archive
> - Installing symfony/validator (v6.2.10): Extracting archive
> - Installing symfony/polyfill-intl-normalizer (v1.27.0): Extracting archive
> - Installing symfony/polyfill-intl-grapheme (v1.27.0): Extracting archive
> - Installing symfony/string (v6.2.8): Extracting archive
> - Installing psr/container (2.0.2): Extracting archive
> - Installing symfony/service-contracts (v3.2.1): Extracting archive
> - Installing symfony/serializer (v6.2.10): Extracting archive
> - Installing symfony/routing (v6.2.8): Extracting archive
> - Installing symfony/http-foundation (v6.2.10): Extracting archive
> - Installing psr/http-message (1.0.1): Extracting archive
> - Installing symfony/psr-http-message-bridge (v2.1.4): Extracting archive
> - Installing symfony/process (v6.2.10): Extracting archive
> - Installing symfony/polyfill-php72 (v1.27.0): Extracting archive
> - Installing symfony/polyfill-intl-idn (v1.27.0): Extracting archive
> - Installing symfony/polyfill-iconv (v1.27.0): Extracting archive
> - Installing symfony/mime (v6.2.10): Extracting archive
> - Installing psr/event-dispatcher (1.0.0): Extracting archive
> - Installing symfony/event-dispatcher-contracts (v3.2.1): Extracting archive
> - Installing symfony/event-dispatcher (v6.2.8): Extracting archive
> - Installing psr/log (3.0.0): Extracting archive
> - Installing symfony/error-handler (v6.2.10): Extracting archive
> - Installing symfony/http-kernel (v6.2.10): Extracting archive
> - Installing symfony/dependency-injection (v6.2.10): Extracting archive
> - Installing symfony/console (v6.2.10): Extracting archive
> - Installing ralouphie/getallheaders (3.0.3): Extracting archive
> - Installing psr/http-factory (1.0.2): Extracting archive
> - Installing psr/http-client (1.0.2): Extracting archive
> - Installing psr/cache (3.0.0): Extracting archive
> - Installing pear/pear_exception (v1.0.2): Extracting archive
> - Installing pear/console_getopt (v1.4.3): Extracting archive
> - Installing pear/pear-core-minimal (v1.10.13): Extracting archive
> - Installing pear/archive_tar (1.4.14): Extracting archive
> - Installing masterminds/html5 (2.7.6): Extracting archive
> - Installing guzzlehttp/psr7 (2.4.5): Extracting archive
> - Installing guzzlehttp/promises (1.5.2): Extracting archive
> - Installing guzzlehttp/guzzle (7.5.1): Extracting archive
> - Installing doctrine/lexer (1.2.3): Extracting archive
> - Installing egulias/email-validator (3.2.5): Extracting archive
> - Installing doctrine/annotations (1.13.3): Extracting archive
> - Installing composer/semver (3.3.2): Extracting archive
> - Installing asm89/stack-cors (v2.1.1): Extracting archive
> - Installing drupal/core (10.0.9): Extracting archive
> - Installing drupal/core-recommended (10.0.9)
>   49/50 [===========================>]  98%    Install of drupal/core failed
>   The following exception is caused by a process timeout
>   Check https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#process-timeout for details

In Process.php line 1204:

> The process "'/usr/bin/unzip' -qq '/app/drupal/vendor/composer/tmp-474185fb585211701bb055d78240c392' -d '/app/drupal/vendor/composer/020e9631'" exceeded the timeout of 300 seconds.

I can see that the issue is that there is a time-out, and I can resolve the issue by setting the COMPOSER_PROCESS_TIMEOUT environment variable > 300 seconds. However, when I do not mount a volume the installation has no issue.

### Environment Information

- Windows 10 Enterprise 22H2 19045.2965
- Docker version 24.0.2, build cb74dfc
- Composer version 2.5.8 2023-06-09 17:13:21

Comment: Most people use a distrubtion such as DDev or Lando, which utilizes Docker under the hood, but manages all the Drupal stuff for you. I personally use DDev.

Comment: Docker bind mounts can be really slow on Windows.

Comment: I recommend instead installing Composer on your computer. And DDEV.

Comment: Are you using WSL? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65285379/docker-volume-mapping-windows-incredible-slow

Comment: The conventional wisdom is that you should use WSL2 to obtain the Linux distro, but do everything from inside the Linux box itself and avoid bind mounts. It is a night and day difference.

Comment: @Kevin I'm going to try to switch to the WSL2 instance and see if that works better. From my testing, it does seem to be a mounting issue. 

Hopefully I will have an update latter today.

Comment: And just to be clear, the most straightforward way to run Composer is to just install it on your computer.

Comment: I'm on a Windows machine, so their php cannot be installed. Therefore I have to use a different solution. 

What I find interesting is that Composer does have a Windows installation, but it requires a PHP path of course. So unless I'm missing something I have not found a way to do that. Unless I install composer through WSL.

Comment: I don't know what you mean about not being able to install PHP on Windows. PHP.net distributes official Windows builds.

Comment: @cilefen that is news to me. I did not know there was a windows installation for PHP.

I found a solution that worked and created a git repository. 

What I found is that using WSL and Docker has made for a good development environment. 

https://github.com/NathanHealea/windows-drupal-development